# UIScrollView Zoom not working in iOS 7 but working perfectly in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios8

I am zooming an image in UIScrollView. In iPhone-4S having iOS 7, its not working. But working perfectly on iOS 8. Even in simulator it is working perfectly on 4s having iOS 8. Any idea?

Here is i'm returning view in Delegate Method as below,

```
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate method
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return pictureView;
}
```

Hierarchy used is as below,

- UIScrollView

  - UIView (Outlet as PictureView)

    - UIImageView

Comment: Are you using auto layout for your views? I'm having what seems like the same issue, and I wonder if auto layout is the culprit. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

"The UIScrollView class can have a delegate that must adopt the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. For zooming and panning to work, the delegate must implement both viewForZoomingInScrollView: and scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:; in addition, the maximum (maximumZoomScale) and minimum ( minimumZoomScale) zoom scale must be different."

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/maximumZoomScale

Comment: Thanks but i've implemented everything you mentioned. In-fact  its working on every device (4s, 5, 6, 6+). The only problem i'm facing is its not working on iOS 7.

Comment: Last piece of advice I could possibly give you is uninstall/reinstall the app to the phone running iOS 7. Also try doing a clean of the build by pressing cmd+shift+k in Xcode. I've no idea what else could be the problem. Good luck

Comment: is there any solution for this problem ?